# Purpose of the ivy.xml for publishing artifacts?

Tags: build, gradle, ivy

I make a Gradle build and when use **ivy-publish** plugin I generate jars and  **ivy.xml** descriptor with the configurations and dependencies of my project, but what is the purpose of this file? Why is needed for runtime applications which use my build to know which jars to provide or..??

Answer (score 3):

The ivy.xml file is the metadata file for your module.

An ivy file is divided into the following sections:

```
<publications>
An ivy module can publish multiple files. The purpose of this section is to 
list them
</publications>

<configurations>
This section describes the various logical file groups that can exist in your 
module
</configurations>

<dependencies>
This section describes the dependencies that might exist on other modules.
One can create mappings between different configurations here as well.
</dependencies>
```

---

At a minimum you need the publications section. It lists the files available. So if I make a request for "moduleA", the ivy client knows what files to download.

Configurations are optional and a difficult concept to initially grasp but they allow you to control sub-sets of the published files for download. For example you only want the binary files or source packages.

Finally dependencies. This enables an ivy client to not only download ModuleA's files, but files belonging to other modules that ModuleA depends on. Generally these are 3rd party libraries that might be required to compile the code, or need to be additionally be on your classpath at runtime. Ivy can do this for you automatically. (Again the contents of these classpaths can be customized using configurations: jars needed to "compile" at "runtime" or when "test"ing the code)